# Dash app not rendering design/ taking into account color etc

Tags: python, frontend, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to add a navigation bar on a new Dash app.

If I run the code straight from [dash website](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/) the output does not render properly.

What it is supposed to look like:

[image]

What I get locally `(Dash 2.7.0 + chrome + dbc 1.2.1)`:

[image]

I have seen other strange behavior such as text in two `dbc.col` on the same `dbc.row` not showing up side by side. I don't know if that is related.

Code:

```
import dash
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = dash.Dash()

PLOTLY_LOGO = "https://images.plot.ly/logo/new-branding/plotly-logomark.png"

search_bar = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type="search", placeholder="Search")),
        dbc.Col(
            dbc.Button(
                "Search", color="primary", className="ms-2", n_clicks=0
            ),
            width="auto",
        ),
    ],
    className="g-0 ms-auto flex-nowrap mt-3 mt-md-0",
    align="center",
)

navbar = dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Container(
        [
            html.A(
                # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(html.Img(src=PLOTLY_LOGO, height="30px")),
                        dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand("Navbar", className="ms-2")),
                    ],
                    align="center",
                    className="g-0",
                ),
                href="https://plotly.com",
                style={"textDecoration": "none"},
            ),
            dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler", n_clicks=0),
            dbc.Collapse(
                search_bar,
                id="navbar-collapse",
                is_open=False,
                navbar=True,
            ),
        ]
    ),
    color="dark",
    dark=True,
)


# add callback for toggling the collapse on small screens
@app.callback(
    Output("navbar-collapse", "is_open"),
    [Input("navbar-toggler", "n_clicks")],
    [State("navbar-collapse", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_navbar_collapse(n, is_open):
    if n:
        return not is_open
    return is_open

app.layout = navbar
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define a stylesheet in order for your `className` references to take effect:

```
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import dash
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

PLOTLY_LOGO = "https://images.plot.ly/logo/new-branding/plotly-logomark.png"

search_bar = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type="search", placeholder="Search")),
        dbc.Col(
            dbc.Button(
                "Search", color="primary", className="ms-2", n_clicks=0
            ),
            width="auto",
        ),
    ],
    className="g-0 ms-auto flex-nowrap mt-3 mt-md-0",
    align="center",
)

navbar = dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Container(
        [
            html.A(
                # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(html.Img(src=PLOTLY_LOGO, height="30px")),
                        dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand("Navbar", className="ms-2")),
                    ],
                    align="center",
                    className="g-0",
                ),
                href="https://plotly.com",
                style={"textDecoration": "none"},
            ),
            dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler", n_clicks=0),
            dbc.Collapse(
                search_bar,
                id="navbar-collapse",
                is_open=False,
                navbar=True,
            ),
        ]
    ),
    color="dark",
    dark=True,
)


# add callback for toggling the collapse on small screens
@app.callback(
    Output("navbar-collapse", "is_open"),
    [Input("navbar-toggler", "n_clicks")],
    [State("navbar-collapse", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_navbar_collapse(n, is_open):
    if n:
        return not is_open
    return is_open


app.layout = navbar
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: It works, wonderful,, I am new to Dash and really appreciate you took the time to answer.

Comment: You're welcome! If this was exactly what you were looking for then please consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer.